# Trying to store 3 values an a byte variable

Tags: java

if i want to store 3 numbers, let's say 1,2 and 3 in a variable of type byte , any suggestions of how to access it from a test class?
i tried  to access it from the test class it won't accept any value of those 3
Here is my code :

```
public class Type {

private byte[] dogType = {1 , 2 , 3};

public void setType(byte[] TypeIn ) {
        dogType = TypeIn;
    }
```

Comment: *i tried to access it from the test class...* - show this code.

Comment: Why do you want to use a byte array? Unless you're using huge arrays or using serial communication, it seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

For these purposes it is much better to use `enum`:

```
public enum DogType {
  HUSKY, BULLDOG, POODLE
}

.....
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DogType dogType = HUSKY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using static variables and methods

```
private static byte[] dogType = {1 , 2 , 3};

public static void setType(byte[] TypeIn ) {
        dogType = TypeIn;
}

public static byte[] getDogType() {

    return dogType;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{

    byte[] dogType2 = {4,5,6};
    setType(dogType2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getDogType()));
}
```

**output**

```
[4, 5, 6]
```